# python.dll in system32 with AMD64 and win32 installed

Tags: python, windows

The standard Python installer places the pythonXY.dll in Windows' system32. If I install the 32bit and the 64bit version, there is only one pythonXY.dll in the system32 folder, but still both interpreters work. I was under the impression every interpreter needs its own archtecture specific dll. Also the Dependency walker tells me the same dll is used for both interpreters. Still each displays AMD64 or win32 respectively in its header once called. How does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 32 bit emulator (known as [WOW64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384249.aspx)) has a parallel system directory named SysWOW64. The 32 bit DLL is found in there.
The system transparently maps requests to access system32 from 32 bit processes into requests to access SysWOW64. That is performed by the [File System Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx).

Comment: OK, so the emulator "redirects" the dll calls. In this case Dependency Walker is not displaying the correct path then, good to know. Thank you!

Comment: Yes the redirector can confuse Dependency Walker. You need to read it through the eyes of a 32 bit process. When a 32 bit process says system32, that is actually mapped to SysWOW64. Can be confusing until you get used to it.

Comment: So, does this answer your question?